# Prometheus auto-discovery can't get NodeJS active services on K8s

Tags: node.js, prometheus

I have set up Prometheus in my Kubernetes Google Cluster and it collects many services but not the NodeJS micro-service I have created.

The NodeJS service is detected by Prometheus because I can see it in the status -> Service Discovery but it is not an active target.

[image]

I also used an nginx-ingress to expose my NodeJS service to the internet and I can even navigate to the `/metrics` endpoint:

[image]

My NodeJS service uses express and [appmetrics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/appmetrics-prometheus/v/3.1.0) is set up for the `/metrics` endpoint.

How can I debug this? What can I do to check why Prometheus is failing to make this service an active target?

PS I have installed Prometheus with the following command and didn't change anything:

```
helm install prometheus \
  --namespace=monitoring \
  --set server.ingress.hosts={my.address.com} \
  --set server.ingress.tls[0].hosts[0]=my.address.com \
  --set server.ingress.tls[0].secretName=my-address-com-tls \
  --set server.ingress.enabled=true \
  --set server.ingress.annotations.'kubernetes\.io/ingress\.class'=nginx \
  --set server.ingress.annotations.'cert-manager\.io/issuer'=monitoring-issuer \
stable/prometheus
```

Comment: Did you found the issue ? what you were missing, I'm facing the same problem

Comment: @SushinPv you must annotate your services. Check the following articles, you will find it helpful. https://www.acagroup.be/en/blog/auto-discovery-of-kubernetes-endpoint-services-prometheus/

Comment: Yes, I got this article yesterday and fixed the issue